# gcc: command not found

Tags: docker, nodemcu

My previously working Docker build started throwing this error, using a clone of the sources obtained yesterday:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools/spiffsimg'
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -I. -I../../app/
spiffs -I../../app/include -DNODEMCU_SPIFFS_NO_INCLUDE --include spiffs_typedefs
.h main.c ../../app/spiffs/spiffs_cache.c ../../app/spiffs/spiffs_check.c ../../
app/spiffs/spiffs_gc.c ../../app/spiffs/spiffs_hydrogen.c ../../app/spiffs/spiff
s_nucleus.c  -o spiffsimg
make[2]: gcc: Command not found
make[2]: *** [spiffsimg] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools/spiffsimg'
make[1]: *** [spiffsimg/spiffsimg] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools'
make: *** [spiffs-image-remove] Error 2
```

Older clones of the source still build without errors.

It does build 0x00000.bin and 0x10000.bin using the latest sources, but doesn't build nodemcu_float_master_########-####.bin nor nodemcu_integer_master_########-####.bin.

Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an older version of the Docker image. `gcc` was added to it [two months ago](https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/commit/db608fde8957a2d1b63656c4c4026ea09d93db12#diff-3254677a7917c6c01f55212f86c57fbf). So, run

```
docker pull marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

to pull the latest version from Docker Hub. Docker doesn't automatically ensure you have the latest version if you downloaded the image before.

Comment: So the toolchain on my ubuntu virtual likely needs to be updated too -- will apt-get update [or upgrade] do it?